# Order by Descending and continue with the same set of group

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

I want records in descending order of `DATE` and continue with the same set of group i.e. here the MAX date is `2018-10-25 00:00:00.000` then the next 3 records should be of `REC = 5`

```
REC DATE
===========================
1   2018-01-02 00:00:00.000
1   2018-01-03 00:00:00.000
1   2018-01-04 00:00:00.000
2   2018-06-01 00:00:00.000
2   2018-06-02 00:00:00.000
3   2018-03-01 00:00:00.000
3   2018-05-02 00:00:00.000
3   2018-01-03 00:00:00.000
3   2018-08-04 00:00:00.000
3   2018-10-05 00:00:00.000
4   2018-10-06 00:00:00.000
5   2018-10-25 00:00:00.000
5   2018-05-03 00:00:00.000
5   2018-09-09 00:00:00.000
```

This is what I have tried but no success.

```
SELECT t1.REC, t1.DATE
FROM TEMP AS t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT REC, MAX(DATE) AS MaxDate
            FROM TEMP
            GROUP BY REC) AS t2
ON (t1.REC = t2.REC AND t1.DATE = t2.MaxDate)
```

Expected result should be something like this:

```
REC DATE
===============================
5   2018-10-25 00:00:00.000
    ..........{Remaining dates of `REC` 5}
4   2018-10-06 00:00:00.000
    ..........{Remaining dates of `REC` 4}
3   2018-10-05 00:00:00.000
    ..........{Remaining dates of `REC` 3}
2   2018-06-02 00:00:00.000
    ..........{Remaining dates of `REC` 2}
1   2018-01-04 00:00:00.000
    ..........{Remaining dates of `REC` 1}
```

Comment: what is the expected result like ?

Comment: MAX (DATE) is per REC or overall ?

Comment: @Squirrel It should be per REC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

max_date is maximum date per REC

```
SELECT  *, max_date = MAX(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY REC)
FROM    yourtable
ORDER BY max_date DESC, DATE DESC
```